# WiFi Connection to ADSL Modem based on MAC

Tags: wifi, bandwidth, mac-address, dsl

Recently my desktop machine is under attack and someone is leeching my DSL bandwidth.
After consultation I find out I can tell my modem to ***only*** accept wifi connection according to system MAC address. (mac address of system NIC).
I want to know how exactly it works and if it prevent connection from any undefined machines?
any other ideas is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the WLAN connections to known MAC addresses allows only connections from WLAN lients that have a defined MAC address...

This helps only a lttle bit as a MAC address can be spoofed.

A help in your case is difficult as you say that you desktop machine is under attack. The question is: Where does the attack originate?

If the attack originates from te WLAN then restricting the WLAN to only known MACs could help (with the aove mentioned limitation).

If the attack originats from your WAN (the DSL connection) then restricting the WLAN does not help.

I suspect hat you're attacked from the WAN (DSL) as if anyone has access to your WAN it does not have to use your desktop computer to use bandwith.

Comment: I don't know the origin of attack. First the ISP says only me and me can use the DSL connection because the connection is phone line specific. So WIFI is the logical choice. YES? on the another note anything in addition to that MAC restriction?